# Sorting an array of numbers in VBS

Tags: arrays, sorting, vbscript

i would like to Sort an array in vbs, so the numbers which are contained in the array are ascending. I'm reading the numbers from a text file

```
    Sub Main()
Dim Werte(10)
Dim c  
Dim fso  
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set c = fso.Drives  
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("Y:\Benutzer\Desktop\Werte.txt",1)
Dim strLine
Dim i
i=0
do while not objFileToRead.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFileToRead.ReadLine()
    Werte(i)=strLine
    i=i+1
loop
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing

for x=LBound(Werte) To UBound(Werte) - 1 Step 1
    for j= 0 to UBound(Werte)-1
        if Werte(j)>Werte(j+1) then
            temp=Werte(j+1)
            Werte(j+1)=Werte(j)
            Werte(j)=temp
        end if
    next
next 

PATH="Y:\Benutzer\Desktop\Werte_sortiert.txt"
Array_ToTextFile Werte,PATH
End Sub

Function Array_ToTextFile(a,path)  

    Const ForWriting = 2  

    Dim fso  

    Dim writer  

    Dim i  

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

    Set writer = fso.OpenTextFile(path,ForWriting,True)  

    For i = lbound(a) to ubound(a)  
        writer.writeline a(i)  
    Next  

    writer.close  
End Function  
Main
```

Text file looks like this:

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0

Result looks like this:

0
1
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

The number 10 should be at the end, but is at the 3rd position after sorting. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Although this is answered, I just wanted to add that you really don't need to read each line. You can read the entire file upfront and then Split the data on vbCrLf delim. Or you can use System.Collections.ArrayList and add each line into sorted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison. If you change line 21 from:

```
    if Werte(j)>Werte(j+1) then
```

to:

```
    if Int(Werte(j))>Int(Werte(j+1)) then
```

it will sort correctly.